# Breaking downs strings to multiple objects based on its input

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I've data which I need to break it down into multiple objects and return it.

Below is the sample data

```
const DATA = {
  text: "\nDo you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page.",
  EntityRanges: [
    { 
      type:"LINK",
      offset:2,
      length:2, 
      data: { target:null, url:"/index.html", description:null }
    },
    {
      type:"LINK",
      offset:84,
      length:16,
      data: { target:null, url:"/index.html", description:null }
    }
  ]
};
```

Now, I loop `EntityRanges` and for each item, I check `offset` & `length` and break the text.

[Stackblitz Link to my working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ex6pzu).

As per the example, text should be broken down like the following

```
- Do, type 'link'
- you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our , type 'text'
- customer support, type 'link'
- page., type 'text'
```

So my expected output should be like this,

```
[
  {
    "type": "LINK",
    "text": "Do",
    "data": {
      "target": null,
      "url": "/index.html",
      "description": null
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "TEXT",
    "text": "you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our ",
    "data": {}
  },
  {
    "type": "LINK",
    "text": "customer support ",
    "data": {
      "target": null,
      "url": "/index.html",
      "description": null
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": " page.",
    "data": {},
  }
]
```

But I'm not getting the expected result. Please Help.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the below solutions, I've still have some issue.

`offset` Value will always start from `0`.

```
text: "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact KLM? Please visit our customer support page.",

Offset: 0,Length: 2 - Do
Offset: 83, Length: 16 - customer support
```

But I get the below output,

```
[
  {
    "type": "link",
    "text": "D",
    "data": {
      "target": null,
      "url": "/index.html",
      "description": null
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": " you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our",
    "data": {}
  },
  {
    "type": "link",
    "text": " customer suppor",
    "data": {
      "target": null,
      "url": "/index.html",
      "description": null
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "text": " page",
    "data": {}
  }
]
```

Example in the [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-capufh?file=index.ts)

Comment: @NinaScholz -  Could you please help with this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use it: [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

This is an ugly example just to explain a possible solution.

```js
const DATA = {
  text: "Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? " + 
        "Please visit our customer support page.",
  EntityRanges: [
    { 
      type:"LINK",
      offset:0,
      length:2, 
      data: { target:null, url:"/index.html", description:null }
    },
    {
      type:"LINK",
      offset:83,
      length:16,
      data: { target:null, url:"/index.html", description:null }
    }
  ]
};

var last = 0, result = [];
DATA.EntityRanges.forEach(function(e) {
    var text = DATA.text.substring(last, e.offset);
    if (text != "") {
        result.push({"type": "text", "text": text, data: {}});
    }
    result.push({"type": "link", "text": DATA.text.substring(e.offset, e.offset+e.length), "data": e.data});
    last = e.offset+e.length; 
});

var text = DATA.text.substring(last, DATA.text.length-1);
if (text != "") {
    result.push({"type": "text", "text": text, data: {}});
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works, I get expected output. But can this logic be simplified even further ?

Comment: The logic is pretty simple. You split the string and if there is some text in the middle, you put it as text. You could use subfunctions for beautify the code, for example `addLink and `addText` (or simply `addItem(type, text, data)`) but the logic is the same.

Comment: Before my string starts I've `\n`, `offset:2, length:2` and space is missing out, If i do `offset:2, length:3` `y` is missing out. any idea ?

Comment: Does your offset start from 1 or from 0?

Comment: offset starts from 0

Comment: offset starts from 1

Comment: With `\nDo`, `offset:2` and `length:2`, you'll have the first item of type text with a `\n` and the second element of type link with `Do`, so it's correct. I've updated my answer with your new text.

Comment: than offset starts from `0,2` which Wil bring DO

Comment: I didn't get what you mean

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that between every `LINK` is a `TEXT`. Further, I couldn't test `.flat()` due to my browser being ancient, so if somebody could confirm the code to be working, I'd be grateful.

The idea is as follows: We `map` over `entityRanges`, constructing two objects on each step. The first being based on the `LINK`, the second's text based on the difference between the current and the next `LINK`. We return those two inside an array, so at the end of `map` we receive an array of array of objects. Thus, we apply `flat` and voila, an array of objects.

```js
var data = {text:"Do you have questions or comments and do you wish to contact ABC? Please visit our customer support page.",EntityRanges:[{type:"LINK",offset:1,length:2,data:{target:null,url:"/index.html",description:null}},{type:"LINK",offset:84,length:16,data:{target:null,url:"/index.html",description:null}}]};

let res = data.EntityRanges.map((c,i,a) => ([
  {type: c.type, text: data.text.slice(c.offset - 1, c.offset - 1 + c.length),data: c.data},
  {type: "TEXT", text: data.text.slice(c.offset - 1 + c.length, a[i + 1] ? a[i + 1].offset - 1: data.text.length - 1), data: {}}
])).flat();

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I don't understand this, c,i,a ? `c` is each `range` `i` is index What is `a` ?

Comment: @user007 `a` is the array we are sequencing. So instead of e.g. saying `data.EntityRanges[i + 1]` we just say `a[i + 1]`.

Comment: I got one issue, `{text:"/nDo}`, my data is having `\n` using css I break the line.  So using the offset value `2,2`. A space is missing. Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: If I do the `offset: 2, length: 3` then `y` is missing out

Comment: @user007 I changed some slice parameters, let me know whether this works better.

Comment: Perfect :-) Thanks so much

Comment: @user007 I forgot to add the `.flat()` in the previous edit, so I added that again!

Comment: Oops, one more issue now I get only this  `" customer suppor"`

Comment: Check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-capufh?file=index.ts

Comment: `"offset": 84 "length": 16` should bring `customer support` but it shows only `customer suppor`

Comment: That is your data, we splice starting at (84 - 1) and grab all until (84 + 16 - 1) so the logic itself is sound. Also add .flat() after `]))`. I feel like the whole unclean data stems from the additionally added `\n`. Can you remove it from your data and add it later? Or better: You added a +1 to your first data offset, so add +1 to your second offset too (84 -> 85).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197046/discussion-between-user007-and-assoron).

Comment: If der is only one array items in `entityRanges`, den the splitting is not working